# Why can't I write more than 2GB?

Tags: c, ubuntu, virtualbox, bandwidth

I am using this code to measure the writing bandwidth of my computer. The program needs two parameters, the name of the file that we are going to write and the amount of MB.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct timeval tv0, tv1;
    int chunkSize = 128, res;
    char str[chunkSize];
    
    if (argc != 3)
    perror("Usage: file_name Mb.");
     
    int megabytes = atoi(argv[2]);
    int sizeWrite = megabytes*1024*1024;
    int sizeWriteAux = sizeWrite;

    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen (argv[1], "w+");

    res = gettimeofday(&tv0, NULL);
    if (res < 0) {
         perror ("gettimeofday");
    }
    
    while (sizeWriteAux > 0) {
     fwrite(str , 1 , chunkSize , fp );
        sizeWriteAux -= chunkSize;
    }
    
    res = gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
    if (res < 0) {
         perror ("gettimeofday");
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    double secs = (((double)tv1.tv_sec*1000000.0 + (double)tv1.tv_usec) - ((double)tv0.tv_sec*1000000.0 + (double)tv0.tv_usec))/1000000.0;
    printf("Time: %f \n", secs);
    
    double x = sizeWrite/secs;
    double y = megabytes/secs;
    printf("Bandwith: %f bytes x sec \n", x);
    printf("Bandwith: %f Mbytes x sec \n", y);

    return(0);
}
```

The program works correctly up to 2047 MB, but as of 2048 it does not write anything and results in infinite bandwidth without returning any error.

I'm running this program on an Ubuntu 20 in VirtualBox, with 12GB RAM and 10 GB of free disk memory.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Check `printf("INT_MAX is %d\n", INT_MAX);` (remember to `#include <limits.h>`) the greatest value your `int`s can be, maybe use `size_t` in your code.

Comment: `atoi()` is a very basic function with no error checking to speak off. Prefer `strtol()` (or a *cousin*: `strtoull()`).

Comment: What about running this with your favorite debugger?

Comment: There are also several other issues with your benchmarking attempt.  First, you're not checking for any error - you don't actually know if *anything* gets written.  Second, `fwrite()` buffers writes so you don't know how many bytes actually do get written for each `fwrite()` call, nor in how many actual `write()` system calls.  Third, since `fwrite()` buffers data that gets flushed when `fclose()` is called, you need to account for the time used by `fclose()` too in your total IO time.

Comment: And on Linux, [you can't even do `write()` calls of 2GB](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html#NOTES): "On Linux, `write()` (and similar system calls) will transfer at
       most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of
       bytes actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and
       64-bit systems.)"

Comment: The first couple of chapters in any C programming book typically addresses numerical limits of integers. In general, the number 2047Mb should make a programmer's mind to stir out of reflex. 2048Mb * 1024 = 2.097*10^6 kb.  Then *1024 again to get bytes. 2.147*10^9. Now where did I see that number before? Oh right, in the first chapters of my C programming book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int megabytes = atoi(argv[2]);
int sizeWrite = megabytes*1024*1024;
int sizeWriteAux = sizeWrite;
```

You're using `int`. It seems, that on your system `sizeof(int) == 4 (bytes)`.
Since `int` is `signed` and one bit is for the sign, you can utilize only 31 bits.

2^31 = 2147483648 (2G)

If you would have used `unsigned int` instead, then

2^32 = 4294967296 (4G)

What difference a bit can make, right?

Now imagine, you would have used `(long) long int`, namely 64 bits.

And you should be wary about the limit of the file-size of your underlying filesystem. Fat for example has a limit of max 2G for a file.

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth `x` and `y` is -inf and inf respectively due to under and overflow because `sizeWrite` is positive and `megabytes` is negative while `secs` is close to `0`. megabytes is negative due to overflow in `sizeWrite = megabytes*1024*1024` as the value is greater than 2^31 - 1 for a sizeof(int) == 4.  `secs` is close to `0` because `sizeWriteAux` is negative as it's initialized to `megabytes` which in turn means the while loop doesn't run at all.  The first order fix is:

```
unsigned long sizeWrite = megabytes*1024*1024;
unsigned long sizeWriteAux = sizeWrite;
```

Your program crashes if both arguments are not specified.  You are missing error checks in general.  Per fclose(2):

> Typically, filesystems do not flush buffers when a file is closed.  If you need to be sure that the data is physically stored on the underlying disk, use fsync(2).

You also need a check on secs to ensure it's large enough so you avoid the overflow of `x` and `y`.  Use unsigned types when your values are positive.

This might be interesting to you:

```
file=...
size=...
block_size=128
time dd if=/dev/zero of=$file bs=$block_size count=$(($size * 1024 * 1024 / $block_size))
```

You will probably see performance improve with `block_size = 4096 * n` where n is at least 1.